MFT supposedly corrupt, chkdsk doesn't fix it
I'm trying to make a backup image of my SSD on which Windows is installed, using Macrium Reflect Workstation.
The first time I tried, it was aborted somewhere in the middle and the logs mention it's due to a CRC check failure (error code 23).
I ran chkdsk c: /r and rebooted. When that was complete I tried another image backup, but this time I get an error quite at the beginning, saying that the MFT is damaged (error code 6) and an instruction to run chkdsk c: /r. Running that again doesn't help (I tried a couple of times and the error persists).
Is there another way to check what is wrong with the MFT, and fix it? Or can I somehow make an image backup without fixing the MFT?

A little bit of context: I'm actually trying to make this backup because my Legion 7 laptop will get a harware repair, because it's WiFi is broken: yesterday suddenly the WiFi connection dropped, in Device Manager the Killer WiFi driver says it's not working, and rebooting, driver update + BIOS update didn't fix it. So it's possible that some event happened (e.g. overheating, the laptop was in heavy use and felt really hot) that caused both WiFi to be broken and some disk errors. But I'm using the laptop now (with Ethernet cable) without further issues.

Update
I've tried skipping the MFT integrity check, but then during the backup I got the CRC check failure (code 23) again.
This is what CrystalDiskInfo says:


Try TestDisk. Googling for "recover mbr" will give many more suggestions.

You could try skipping the integrity check Macrium Reflect does. Launch the Macrium software to enter its main interface, select Other Tasks from the upper left corner, and click on Edit Defaults and Settings. Select Verify File System from the left panel and untick the checkbox next to Verify the integrity of the file systems being backed up. Then click on OK to save the change. You could also try a more elaborate chkdsk, like chkdsk c: /r /f /x

@Silbee elaborate chkdsk I had tried already. I can skip MFT check, but then during backup I get the CRC error that I got the first time again.

@JoepvanSteen I've added the SMART screenshot. I guess it gets relatively hot even though I'm not doing much right now. I assume it gets even hotter at times when CPU and/or GPU are heavily used.

@Silbee changing Macrium Reflect settings to skip verification of the file system and ignore bad clusters enabled me to create a backup indeed, so if you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

@herman thanks for dropping by and letting us know. Hope the backup does the job and things will get fixed for you. I added my comment as answer.

You could try skipping the integrity check Macrium Reflect does. Launch the Macrium software to enter its main interface, select Other Tasks from the upper left corner, and click on Edit Defaults and Settings. Select Verify File System from the left panel and untick the checkbox next to Verify the integrity of the file systems being backed up.
The obvious drawback is that your data might turn out to be corrupt.

In Advanced settings > Advanced backups there is an additional setting to ignore bad sectors. I needed to check that as well.

I had the same problem yesterday running Macruim backup on my system volume. Macruim is excellant at finding and reporting errors. Don't bypass anything, you won't have a valid backup.
Chkdsk /r will not work for your system volume while it is active. It will work for any drive you haven't booted from.
Chkdsk C: /f/r/x run in admin mode on Windows Ten worked for me. It schedules the chkdsk to run at startup before files are open.
Another method is to boot your system into recovery mode and run the command from there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk?tabs=event-viewer
https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/run-or-stop-chkdsk-on-startup.html
Let me know how you end up resolving your problem. Larry

I did bypass the checks to make the backup. I ended up getting another laptop since they couldn't get things fixed after a motherboard replacement, and at least the files I needed to restore were valid. On the new system I couldn't restore the full image anyway.

What do you mean by backup image? Do you want your copy to be bootable from another hard drive, or just want to backup up the files to reinstall the OS on the same drive?
If you want a bootable copy, you could try using Clonezilla, it's pretty straightforward.
If you just want to keep a copy of your files, you could try using Guymager, Kali Linux has it by default, but there are other distros that come with it as well, and you can probably install it with a couple commands either.
Or even a plain robocopy "C:" "{Dest_drive}:" if it's Windows and it's still bootable

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
